# Dynamic Fluent Mapping with EF4.1

Tags: reflection, entity-framework-4.1, linq-expressions

I want to dynamically create my data model to work with some existing classes and a custom XML mapping file because I have lots of existing tables and lots of existing business classes (maybe crazy, I don't know).

For properties that use different column names or don't correspond to existing columns I want to call .Ignore() and .HasColumnName() but I want to do it dyanically.

So I want to be able to make calls like this but I want to make them dynamically based on reflection and an XML config file using Linq.Expressions (which I've never had occasion to use):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.QuantityInStock).HasColumnName("UnitsInStock");
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Ignore(p => p.QuantityInStock);
```

This is what I'm trying (ultimately I'll refer to my XML map to determine which properties to map and which to ignore):

```
Type entityType = typeof(Product);

var config = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity")
    .MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
    .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);

var ignore = config.GetType().GetMethod("Ignore").MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

var paramEx = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(paramEx, "QuantityInStock"), paramEx);

ignore.Invoke(config, new[] { lambdaEx });
```

But my lambda expression isn't right:

```
Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication2.Product,System.Int16]]' 
cannot be converted to type 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication2.Product,ConsoleApplication2.Product]]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type argument is wrong for the `Ignore` method. Change your code to this:

```
var paramEx = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
var prop = Expression.Property(paramEx, "QuantityInStock");
var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(prop, paramEx);
var ignore = config.GetType().GetMethod("Ignore").MakeGenericMethod(prop.Type);
```

EDIT: calling `HasColumnName`:

```
var property = config.GetType().GetMethod("Property", new Type[] { lambdaEx.GetType() });
var hasColumnName = property.ReturnType.GetMethod("HasColumnName");

hasColumnName.Invoke(
    property.Invoke(config, new[] { lambdaEx }),
    new[] { "UnitsInStock" });
```

However this does not work for structs excluded from the overload list like `long` or similar,  `property`'s value would be `null` in those cases. Hence you will have to search for the generic `Property` method with `GetMethods` and choose the appropriate one (with or without the `Nullable<T>` type in the `Expression` parameter).

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Can you help me call .HasColumnName()? This is harder because .Property has many overrides and I'm not sure how to get an invoke the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is not the intended purpose of the Fluent API. The whole purpose of the Fluent API is to provide more readable and easy way to configure while giving you the compile time safety. I see non of that with this approach.

Better way to externalize the configuration is to use `EntityTypeConfiguration` class and add these to the `ModelBuilder`.

Comment: Well I have classes with a hundred properties, none of which correspond to columns in the table and I don't want to have to explicitly ignore them all. Better would be to examine the table/model/xml config myself and make the calls to .Ignore dynamically.

Comment: Trying to fit something that was not designed for that purpose will only make matters worse. Better to have a set of EF entities that will be mapped to your business classes.